# I don't understand the kernel of $\Phi$ in Van Kampen's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology

If we have $A_1$, ..., $A_n$, $X=A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and $\Phi:\pi_1(A_1,x_0)\ast\cdots\ast \pi_1(A_n,x_0)\rightarrow \pi_1(X$,x_0) being the extended homomorphism then the Van Kampen theorem states that:

$\pi_1(X,x_0)=\frac{\pi_1(A_1,x_0)\ast\cdots\ast \pi_1(A_n,x_0)}{ker(\Phi)}$

with

$ker(\Phi)=\langle\langle [f]_{A_i}[f]_{A_j}^{-1} \Big| [f]\in\pi_1(A_i\cap A_j\rangle\rangle$

I'm trying to understand, in words, what the group that is the $ker(\Phi)$ is.

For the free product of the fundamental groups, I get that. Its just saying "take loops in the individual $A_i$ and then do them one at a time to your heart's content and that would be a loop in $X$."

But, for the kernel, is it just saying "go ahead and take thoe loops, but remember, if you take a loop in one $A_i$ and then a loop in an $A_j$, check to see if they are actually, secretly, opposites of each other in $A_i\cap A_j$ and, if they are, you can just replace that part with the identity loops (i.e. remove it)."?

If that's right, how does this work in practice? For example, with the [double Torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246516/problems-to-understand-van-kampen-theorem) here, I can see how the $\pi_1(U)=\pi_1(V)=\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ and so the overall free product becomes $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$. But, $U\cap V$ is the shell of a cylinder without a top or bottom and so, to me, it looks like $ker(\Phi)$ is just any loop around the center and then going backwards. But I'm not able to put it together to "see" what the overall fundamental group is.

Answer (score 1):

This kernel is chosen to allow the identification of specific elements in the overall free product. Namely, if you start from the more general setting where $A,B,C$ are groups with two morphisms $\varphi:C\to A$ and $\psi:C\to B$, then you can think of $\varphi(C)$ as a subgroup of $A$ (thus of $A\ast B$) and of $\psi(C)$ as a subgroup of $B$ (thus of $A\ast B$). If you want to formally identify these two subgroups in $A\ast B$, then you have to quotient it by the normal subgroup $N$ generated by the elements of the form $\varphi(c)\psi(c)^{-1}$, $c\in C$, since you will then have in the quotient $(A\ast B)/N$ that
$$[\varphi(c)]=[\varphi(c)\varphi^{-1}(c)\psi(c)]=[\psi(c)]$$
for all $c\in C$. This group is usually denoted
$$(A\ast B)/N=A\underset{C}{\ast} B.$$
What Van Kampen's theorem tells you is that (under the assumption that $X=U\cup V$ where $U,V$ and $U\cap V$ are path-connected open sets of $X$, $x_0\in U\cap V$):
$$\pi_1(X,x_0)\simeq\pi_1(U,x_0)\underset{\pi_1(U\cap V,x_0)}{\ast}\pi_1(V,x_0),$$
where the corresponding morphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are induced by the inclusions $i:U\cap V \to U$ and $j:U\cap V\to V$.
In your example of the double torus, $\pi_1(U,x_0)\simeq \mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ is free generated by two loops $a$ and $b$, $\pi_1(V,x_0)\simeq \mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$ is free generated by two loops $c$ and $d$, and $\pi_1(U\cap V,x_0)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ is free generated by a loop $e$ which checks that $\varphi(e)=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=[a,b]$ and $\psi(e)=cdc^{-1}d^{-1}=[c,d]$, so $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ will have the presentation which is given in the answer you linked, namely
$$\pi_1(X,x_0)\simeq\langle a,b,c,d\,|\,[a,b][c,d]^{-1}\rangle.$$